# Is there a way to do an accessible modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I'm working on a project with Twitter Bootstrap and playing around the [JavaScript components](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) using a screen reader.

When I trigger the modal dialog, Jaws skips the modal going to the next link in the page.

Is there a way to implement a accessible modal?

Another solution that I think is to make a static page to the functionality of the modal, and redirect to this page when the user use a screen reader. Can I detected somehow if the user are using a screen reader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT 2019: N. Hoffmann wrote and maintains an accessible modal component both in [vanilla JS](https://van11y.net/accessible-modal/) (along other components in its [van11y](https://van11y.net) project) and [jQuery](https://a11y.nicolas-hoffmann.net/modal/).
Behavior and styles are easily modified via `data-*` attributes and classes.
It's been tested in way more conditions (screen readers, etc) that what you'd do with your own script ;-)

Also Bootstrap 4 has a fairly accessible modal and Bootstrap 3 in its latest versions (much or all of the Paypal Bootstrap accessibility plugin was backported to 3.3.x).

Modern ressources: **[Access & Use](https://accessuse.eu/en/modal-dialogs.html)** european initiative details a lot of interesting aspects *in a simple manner* and points to other resources, including the latest ARIA Deisgn Pattern.

---

Here's an accessible modal dialog: http://hanshillen.github.com/jqtest/#goto_dialog

Once the modal is activated, keyboard navigation is trapped inside the dialog till it's explicitly closed by the user.

http://irama.org/web/dhtml/lightbox/ details such an accessible implementation (there's little difference between a lightbox and a modal dialog, the important thing is the modal part and keyboard management).
You can also read in *Unofficial copy of the DHTML Style Guide* the [dialog modal](http://www.html5accessibility.com/dhtmlStyleGuide.html#dialogmodal) part and W3C/WAI-ARIA [Making a Dialog Modal](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-wai-aria-practices-20100916/#modal_dialog).

J. Wajsberg wrote a jQuery plugin able to [trap the keyboard input inside a DOM element](https://github.com/julienw/jquery-trap-input) if you need a more DIY approach.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know any solution to detected automatically if user using a screen reader. but there is the google solution to hide a link at the begining of the page (with left:-1000em and position:absolute) that can be activate if you use keyboard and display a "special mode".

```
<a href="#" style="left:-1000em;position:absolute">Screen reader users, click here to turn off Google Instant.</a>
```

for your modal dialog try to use aria and aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive" attribute on the dialog html div. it should announce the content of you dialog box.